# CouchDB Design Document Format

Tags: couchdb

I have a backup of couchdb design documents from an old project. I'm trying to work with this data but I'm not sure what format they are in. Does anyone know? I have a feeling it might be BSON.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you made the backup, but CouchDB uses plain JSON, not BSON (which is MongoDB-specific). If you are talking about the database files CouchDB stores (ending with .couch), these are opaque to the user. If you have a running CouchDB instance (a version < 2.0 is easiest), then you can just put the file in the data folder, and it should be visible in Futon.

You can then backup the design documents to text files - you find [more information about tools for backing up CouchDB in this IBM Cloudant blog post](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/03/22/simple-couchdb-and-cloudant-backup/).